# How to set type when computed property is used?

Tags: typescript, types, computed-properties

I have two interfaces.

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
    weight: number;
}

interface Dog {
    name: string;
    mass: number
}

const attribute = isDog ? 'mass' : 'weight';
const player: Person | Dog = "Object with specific type"

if (player[attribute] === 0) return;
```

I have this error: 
**TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"mass" | "weight"' can't be used to index type 'Person | Dog'.**

The API can return both Dog or Person and it depends on other parameter. I would like to know what is the best way to tell TS that if player is Person use 'weight' and if the player is Dog use 'mass'. I dont want to use "any" type.

Comment: Well, TypeScript is trying to be helpful here. If `attribute` is `"mass"`, but `player` is a `Person`, then it will be a legitimate error, since `Person.mass` doesn't exist

Comment: You shouldn't have to make this distinction from the outside. Both `Person` and `Dog` should expose their mass in the same way (`extends Massive`?) so this doesn't spread over your whole codebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript is actually helpful here: if, for example, `attribute` is `"mass"`, but `player` is a `Person`, then it will be a legitimate error since `mass` property doesn't exist on `Person` instances.

You avoid this error, you need to change the approach. You could add a runtime check of `attribute` actually existing in `player`, but I'd argue that you should use the `isDog` variable (it's just more logical):

```
const isDog = "mass" in player;
const mass = isDog ? player.mass : player.weight;

if (mass === 0) return;
```

*[Try it](https://tsplay.dev/m0LEnm)*.

Answer (score 0):

User @jonsharpe suggested in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69812115/how-to-set-type-when-computed-property-is-used/69812319#comment123407386_69812115) a valuable pattern: converge similar functionality on one property, i.e., if `weight` and `mass` convey the same idea, they should be called the same (notice how both `Person` and `Dog` have `name` property, which conveys the same idea). Usually this is done via objects implementing a common interface (such as `Massive` in this case).

Here's how you can do it:

```
interface Massive {
  mass: number;
}

interface Person extends Massive {
  name: string;
  // other Person-specific properties, no need to repeat `mass`
}

interface Dog extends Massive {
  name: string;
  // other Dog-specific properties, no need to repeat `mass`
}

function doSomethingIfHasMass(value: Massive) {
  if (value.mass === 0) return;

  // otherwise do the thing
}

const player: Person | Dog;

doSomethingIfHasMass(player);
// shouldn't cause compile errors,
// because `Person | Dog` is assignable to `Massive`,
// since each `Person` and `Dog` individually is `Massive`
```

*[Try it](https://tsplay.dev/w11jKw)*.

This should suffice for your problem (although, I'd recommend creating a `Named` interface for `name: string` property as well). There's another function however, that you could find useful. While `hasMass` answers the question *"Does the object has mass?"* (it does if its mass is greater than zero), the `isMassive` would answer the question *"Does the object comply to `Massive` interface?"* (it does if it has "mass" property):

```
function isMassive(value: object): value is Massive {
  return "mass" in value;
}
```

Now you can provide all sorts of objects in your function, and it will silently fail without errors if the object is not of the right shape (whether that behaviour is good for you is your decision):

```
function doSomethingIfMassiveAndHasMass(value: object) {
  if (!isMassive(value)) return;

  if (value.mass === 0) return;

  // otherwise do the thing
}

declare const something: object;

doSomethingIfMassiveAndHasMass(something);
// shouldn't cause compile errors,
// because while any object could be passed in this function,
// only `Massive` objects with non-zero mass will actually trigger its logic
```

*[Try it](https://tsplay.dev/WK84zw), also [see an example](https://tsplay.dev/WJ8vDN)*.